# Why is there an underscore following the "from" in the Twilio Rest API?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

In the [twilio python library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python#testing-your-installation), we have this feature to create messages:

`from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient`

and we can write:

`msg = TwilioRestClient.messages.create(body=myMsgString, from_=myNumber, to=yourNumber)`

My question is simple: why does an underscore follow the `from` parameter? Or why is that the parameter name? Is it because `from` is otherwise a keyword in Python and we differentiate variables from keywords with an underscore suffix? Is that actually necessary in this case?

Comment: You've answered yourself. You can't use `from` as it's a keyword. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) suggests doing this and gives the example of `class_`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `from` would be an invalid argument name, resulting in a `SyntaxError` - it's a python keyword.

Appending a trailing underscore is the recommended way to avoid such conflicts mentioned in the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments):

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption.

Comment: Hey wim, thanks for your answer here! One of my favorite gotchas in the Twilio-Python helper library ;) Can I offer you a shirt for your contribution to the community? Send an email to mspeir@twilio.com for details.

Comment: Hey, I received [the t-shirt](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oQQF7.jpg).  Cheers!